# How to use the useState() hook to open / close all detail tags In ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docusaurus

I have a `useState()` hook to assert or deny the `open` (`isOpen`) attribute of 3 `detail` tags and also 2 `button`(s) to control the hook, all wrapped in a `div`:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const SamplePage = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false); 

    return (
        <div>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    First text detail.
                </summary>
                <p>testing</p>
            </details>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    Second text detail.
                </summary>
                <p>testing</p>
            </details>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    Third text detail.
                </summary>
                <p>testing</p>
            </details>

            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Open All Details.</button>
            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Close All Details.</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
  
ReactDOM.render(<SamplePage/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This code is part of a Docusaurus project, which is similar to Create React App. It includes all the required packages and configuration scripts, including `imports` / `exports`.

In this context, neither button produces the intended `onClick` effect, which is to treat all `isOpen` attributes as part of the `setIsOpen` set and therefore activating the  `useState` hook function to open / close all `detail` elements. Is this an artifact of my set-up or is it the code itself?

Comment: I've converted your code block into a **runnable** example using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (Note that I had to change `samplePage` to `SamplePage`, because component names must start with a capital letter.) As you can see, one of the buttons does expand all the details and the other collapses them (though the buttons are backward). If that's not what you're seeing at your end, please update the MCVE to show the problem.

Comment: Interesting... It's definitely my set-up in this case. Good to know the code itself works.

Comment: Your code does work ..  The casing was the issue . Working sample here! 

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-matsumoto-megqs

Comment: Oddly enough, the casing has no effect. The code loads fine, but the buttons have no `onClick` event. I think there's a dependency missing somewhere, but I can't isolate it. I'll study this more closely when I get the chance. Delete this Q if you wish.

Comment: In fact, it appears to be an issue with the imports and exports. As I said, this code is living in the context of a "Docusaurus" project. It handles all the imports and exports as long as `const React = require("react")`; and `module.exports` are defined. I can't use `const {useState} = React;` or similar statements. For whatever reason, these all throw a `ReferenceError: React is not defined` and other similar errors.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your component must start with a capital letter.

```
const SamplePage = () =>
```

2) You are setting the state incorrectly on each button. You want to set it to `true` on the "Open all details" button, and `false` on the "Close all details" button:

```
<button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Open All Details.</button>
<button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Close All Details.</button>
```

```js
const SamplePage = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false); 

  return (
      <div>
          <details open={isOpen}>
              <summary>
                  First text detail.
              </summary>
              <p>testing</p>
          </details>
          <details open={isOpen}>
              <summary>
                  Second text detail.
              </summary>
              <p>testing</p>
          </details>
          <details open={isOpen}>
              <summary>
                  Third text detail.
              </summary>
              <p>testing</p>
          </details>

          <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Open All Details.</button>
          <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Close All Details.</button>
      </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<SamplePage />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```