# How to employ the useState() hook with config props in a Docusaurus project?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, docusaurus

I'm working with Docusaurus, which provides a `siteConfig.js` as a config props. As such, I have to use this props to build my site components. Working code is formatted like this:

```
const React = require("react");

class SamplePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const siteConfig = this.props.config;
    return <div>{siteConfig.title}</div>;
  }
}

module.exports = SamplePage;
```

I have another segment of working code shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588990/how-to-use-the-usestate-hook-to-open-close-all-detail-tags-in-reactjs), but it uses a different set-up where `const {useState} = React;` is used in place of `const React = require("react");` and `<div id="root">` with `ReactDOM.render(<SamplePage/>, document.getElementById("root"));` in place of `module.exports = SamplePage;`. I understand this allows running code snippets on SE, but it doesn't show me how the imports and exports are supposed to function in the context of this Docusaurus project. What I want to do is incorporate the code segment into the `React.Component` or otherwise construct this component to employ the`useState` hook with the config props in order to assert or deny the `isOpen` attribute of 3 `detail` tags, using 2 `button`(s) to control the hook:

```
const {useState} = React;

const SamplePage = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false); 

    return (
        <div>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    First text detail.
                </summary>
                <p>testing</p>
            </details>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    Second text detail.
                </summary>
                <p>testing</p>
            </details>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    Third text detail.
                </summary>
                <p>testing</p>
            </details>

            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Open All Details.</button>
            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Close All Details.</button>
        </div>
    );
  }

ReactDOM.render(<SamplePage/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

For the code snippet:

```
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

My question is how to combine these code segments. I've tried to construct this component in many different ways, but I can't get the `button`(s) to fire the `onClick()` effect. For example, I tried:

```
const React = require("react");

const SamplePage, {useState} = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false); 
  const siteConfig = this.props.config;

  return (
      <div>
          <details open={isOpen}>
              <summary>
                  First text detail.
              </summary>
              <p>testing</p>
          </details>
          <details open={isOpen}>
              <summary>
                  Second text detail.
              </summary>
              <p>testing</p>
          </details>
          <details open={isOpen}>
              <summary>
                  Third text detail.
              </summary>
              <p>testing</p>
          </details>

          <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Open All Details.</button>
          <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Close All Details.</button>
      </div>
  );
}

module.exports = SamplePage;
```

This throws an "invalid hook call", of course, since I can't actually use the `useState` hook in my current set-up. I get unexpected tokens and reference errors in all my other constructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flip you're true/false bool in your onClicks (open should be true)

Keep in mind your 'open' `onClick` opens the drop-downs just fine but the 'close' `onClick` will only close the drop-downs if the 'open' `onClick` sets state to true first

If you need to export this instead of rendering it to the DOM (and can't/don't want to change to ES6 import statements elsewhere) then change `ReactDom.render()` to:

```
module.exports = SamplePage;
```

Full example:

```
const React = require('react')
const {useState} = React;

const SamplePage = (props) => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false); 
    const siteConfig = props.config

    return (
        <div>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    First text detail.
                </summary>
                <p>testing</p>
            </details>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    Second text detail.
                </summary>
                <p>testing</p>
            </details>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    Third text detail.
                </summary>
                <p>testing</p>
            </details>

            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Open All Details.</button>
            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Close All Details.</button>
        </div>
    );
  }

module.exports = SamplePage;
```

Runnable snippet:

```js
// const React = require('react')
const {useState} = React; //refer to above note

const SamplePage = (props) => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const siteConfig = props.config

    return (
        <div>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    First text detail.
                </summary>
                <p>testing</p>
            </details>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    Second text detail.
                </summary>
                <p>testing</p>
            </details>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    Third text detail.
                </summary>
                <p>testing</p>
            </details>

            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Open All Details.</button>
            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Close All Details.</button>
        </div>
    );
  }

ReactDOM.render(<SamplePage/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This looks fine, but I still have to use `module.exports`. Otherwise, I get this error from the Docusaurus server: "Failed to start [...]: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: "module"'`. Can this error be avoided?

Comment: Where are you importing this component into? can you show that code?

Comment: It's all a bit over my head to be honest. The repository is [here](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus).

Comment: Check my answer I updated to be more clear and added a clear example in addition to the runnable snippet

Comment: I tried the updated code. It looks right to me, but what do I know. This still throws the same error, unfortunately, with the 'sourceType: "module" restriction.

Comment: sorry try that now, you cant use import and module.exports in the same file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201515/discussion-between-lichtung-and-willman-codes).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting object destructuring mixed up with imports.  Here's a breakdown of what you should be doing:

```
// this line imports the react library, which we need in order to
// export a JSX component
const React = require("react");

// this line pulls the useState function out of the React library
// using object destructuring
const { useState } = React;
// it is the same as const useState = React.useState

// we dont need to pass useState in as a prop because its already
// imported in the same file
const SamplePage = props => {
  // and here we don't need to call React.useState because it has been
  // separated into its own variable
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false); 
  const siteConfig = props.config; // functional components don't use this

  return (
      <div>
          <details open={isOpen}>
              <summary>
                  First text detail.
              </summary>
              <p>testing</p>
          </details>
          <details open={isOpen}>
              <summary>
                  Second text detail.
              </summary>
              <p>testing</p>
          </details>
          <details open={isOpen}>
              <summary>
                  Third text detail.
              </summary>
              <p>testing</p>
          </details>

          <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Open All Details.</button>
          <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Close All Details.</button>
      </div>
  );
}

module.exports = SamplePage;
```

let me know if you have any more questions.

**EDIT**

I added the `props` parameter to the function, I accidentally left that out.  Also, when using functional components you don't use the `this` keyword when accessing props, just call it on it's own.

Comment: This looks right, but I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined".

Comment: Just a general note, when you get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ANYTHING' of undefined" that always means that the object the variable is a child of is undefined, not the variable itself.  so in this case, `this` is undefined not `props`

Comment: Your code loads just fine, but the buttons still don't have any effect. It's very strange. I'll need to do some more reading and testing, I suppose.

Comment: Where is the details element coming from?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's a basic html tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201516/discussion-between-lichtung-and-chris-sandvik).